# Calculate on change for each row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an invoice form to generate a PDF. I want to calculate the inputs after the change of the value that the user fills in the form.

I can calculate the first row, but i want to (1) calculate each row and at the end to (2) calculate all the colums properly. For the first step just to the (1) and i will make the total calculation.

The problem is that i generate the rows with dynamic name and id because i post them in an array to the database. For this example the id is the same for every row of inputs.

[image]

**PS:** i cannot make `.change` work and i use `$(document).on('change', '#qty', function (e) { calculateLine(); });` to trigger the calculation function for each input. I dont know why `.change` is not working as it support to, with latest jquery.

**[invoice.php]**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('change', '#qty', function (e) { calculateLine(); });
        $(document).on('change', '#price', function (e) { calculateLine(); });
        $(document).on('change', '#discount', function (e) { calculateLine(); });
        $(document).on('change', '#discountPrice', function (e) { calculateLine(); });

    });
</script>
```

**[invoice.js]**

```
function calculateLine() {

    var qty = parseFloat($('#qty').val());
    var price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
    var discount = parseFloat($('#discount').val());
    var discountPrice = parseFloat($('#discountPrice').val());
    var vat = parseFloat($('#vat').val());

    var netTotal = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var vatAmount = 0;

    if (!qty && qty == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (!price && price == 0) {
        return;
    }

    netTotal = qty * price;

    if ((!discount || discount == 0) && discountPrice != 0) {
        discount = (discountPrice / netTotal) * 100;
    }
    if ((!discountPrice || discountPrice == 0) && discount != 0) {
        discountPrice = (netTotal / 100) * discount;
    }
    if (discountPrice != 0 && discount != 0) {
        discountPrice = (netTotal / 100) * discount;
    }
    if ((!discount || discount == 0) && (!discountPrice || discountPrice == 0)) {
        discountPrice = 0;
        discount = 0;
    }

    total = netTotal - discountPrice;

    if (!total || total == 0) {
        total = 0;
    }
    vatAmount = (total / 100) * vat;

    $('#total').val(total);
    $('#discount').val(discount);
    $('#discountPrice').val(discountPrice);
    $('#vatAmount').val(vatAmount);

    //calculateTotal();
}
```

**[html]**

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-xs-0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" class="checkall">
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-5">
        <textarea type="text" name="invoice[item][{{j}}][description]" class="form-control description" rows="1" ></textarea>
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="text" name="invoice[item][{{j}}][unit]" class="form-control unit" value="" />
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="text" name="invoice[item][{{j}}][qty]" class="form-control qty" value="" />
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="text" name="invoice[item][{{j}}][price]" class="form-control price" value="" />
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="text" name="invoice[item][{{j}}][discount]" class="form-control discount" value="" >
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="text" name="invoice[item][{{j}}][discountPrice]" class="form-control discountPrice" />
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="text" name="invoice[item][{{j}}][total]" class="form-control total" value="" />
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1">
        <input type="text" name="invoice[item][{{j}}][vat]" class="form-control vat" value="{{invcl_vat}}" readonly />
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice[item][{{j}}][vatAmount]" class="form-control vatAmount" value="" readonly />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't shown your HTML, but it's clear from your question that you're using the same `id` (`qty`, etc.) on more than one element. You can't do that. Every `id` must be **unique** on the page. In this case, you'd probably use classes instead.

The general way that you do what you're talking about is indeed to use delegated event handling, then find the containing row, and use that as the starting point looking for descendant inputs using classes rather than `id`s:

```
$("selector-for-the-table").on("change", "input", function() {
    // Get the row containing the input
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");

    // Get the values from _this row's_ inputs, using `row.find` to
    // look only within this row
    var qty = parseFloat(row.find('.qty').val());
    var price = parseFloat(row.find('.price').val());
    var discount = parseFloat(row.find('.discount').val());
    var discountPrice = parseFloat(row.find('.discountPrice').val());
    var vat = parseFloat(row.find('.vat').val());

    // ...
});
```

I've also rooted that on the table, rather than `document`, so it only applies where appropriate.

[Live (Simplified) Example](http://jsbin.com/zunir/1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="price"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="total" disabled></td>
      </tr>
      <!-- ...and so on... -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    $("table").on("change", "input", function() {
      var row = $(this).closest("tr");
      var qty = parseFloat(row.find(".qty").val());
      var price = parseFloat(row.find(".price").val());
      var total = qty * price;
      row.find(".total").val(isNaN(total) ? "" : total);
    });
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

You've said before that the names are dynamic. Surely there is *some* characteristic of the fields you're trying to find that is consistent, or you can *make* them consistent. In the worst case (and I mean in the worst case), you could do something based on position — the first `input` in the row is `row.find("input:eq(0)")`, the second is `row.find("input:eq(1)")`, and so on.

[Live Example Using `eq`](http://jsbin.com/zunir/2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text" disabled></td>
      </tr>
      <!-- ...and so on... -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    $("table").on("change", "input", function() {
      var row = $(this).closest("tr");
      var qty = parseFloat(row.find("input:eq(0)").val());
      var price = parseFloat(row.find("input:eq(1)").val());
      var total = qty * price;
      row.find("input:eq(2)").val(isNaN(total) ? "" : total);
    });
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But avoid that if you possibly can, it's fragile — if you change the order of columns, you have to change your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem is that i have dynamic names (or ids) and i cannot pass them to the script to handle them. I can use static id or all inputs. Let me try your suggestion and revert

Comment: @JohnPriestakos: ("Revert" is not the word you wanted there.) Well, what are the `#qty` and such in your question, then? You can't use those, they're `id`s, but you need to have something to work with. Worst case, you could do it with position stuff (`input:eq(0)` for the first input in the row, `input:eq(1)` for the second one, etc.).

Comment: Your examples were very helpfull. Now i have to correct the `input:eq()` and make it work. (i updated my question with the html code of each row - i removed ids and put them as classes)

Comment: @JohnPriestakos: You're welcome! Just to be clear, you don't need `:eq` if you're using the classes and looking within the row. I couldn't tell from your comment above whether you might still be using them despite having classes (which makes `:eq` unnecessary).

Comment: Its all good with `.class` instead of `:eq` as you suggested before. Thank you for you help. All working well, until the next issue :)